# Не отправляется форма в БД(MySql)

Tags: php, html, форма

Не отправляется заполненная форма HTML в Базу Данных.
Не пойму в чем проблема...
Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>NAME PROJECT</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style/main.css'>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/734652abcf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder="Ник" name="nick"></input><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="вк" name="vk"></input><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="стим" name="steam"></input><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="дискорд" name="discord"></input><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="группа" name="group"></input><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="лвл" name="lvl"></input><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Добавить" name="go">
</form>
<?
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql', 'mysql', 'admins_test');
$nick = $_POST['nick'];
$vk = $_POST['vk'];
$steam = $_POST['steam'];
$discord = $_POST['discord'];
$group = $_POST['group'];
$lvl = $_POST['lvl'];

if(isset($_POST['go'])){
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `admins`(`nick`, `vk`, `steam`, `discord`, `group`, `lvl`) VALUES ('{$nick}', '{$vk}', '{$steam}', '{$discord}', '{$group}, '{$lvl}')");
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте подключение к серверу и базе данных с выводом ошибок:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql', 'mysql') or die(mysqli_error($db));
mysqli_select_db($db, 'admins_test') or die('Cannot select Datebase');
```

Не уверена по поводу фигурных скобок, без них значения переменных тоже передаются, там где $group в SQL-запросе забыли одинарную кавычку:

```
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `admins`(`nick`, `vk`, `steam`, `discord`, `group`, `lvl`) VALUES ('$nick', '$vk', '$steam', '$discord', '$group', '$lvl')");
```